# How to "git log" the entire repository and not just the branch you are on?

Tags: git

The question is simple: I want to see the output of `git log`, but for the entire repository. Currently it just shows the changesets in the branch I am on: `git log --all --source --graph`.

For example, it would be perfect if I could see the last 100 commits in the repository no matter what branch I am on and what branches those commits belong to. Is this possible?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Give this command a try:

```
git log --all --graph --decorate --pretty=oneline --abbrev-commit
```

You already had the right start with `--all --graph`. Adding in `--decorate` will show any branches or tags pointing to a commit, and the others two, `--pretty=oneline --abbrev-commit` are just to clean up and compact the output.

It's best to include the `--pretty` in the command, because `--decorate` won't work if you're using a custom format.

If this is a command you're going to use a lot, you can actually add an alias so it's easy to reuse without typing the whole thing out. For instance, add the following to your `~/.gitconfig`:

```
[alias]
  history = "git log --all --graph --decorate --pretty=oneline --abbrev-commit"
```

Then you can just use `git history` to get the nicely formatted output.

Comment: You can use `--oneline` as another way to spell `--pretty=oneline --abbrev-commit`

Comment: And you could use `git history -n 100` to limit how many commits you see.

Answer (score 1):

You can also use `gitk --all` to show all the commits, that what's you need as well.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if there's a single command to do this. Also, it can be quite confusing since the commits might get interleaved.

I wrote a little [ruby script](http://code.activestate.com/recipes/577572-display-a-git-repository) that prints something like this out but in a format suitable for graphviz's `dot` command to give me a graphical view of the repository history. You could try that. The script is fairly straightforward so you can modify it to print the same information (which is what you're looking for) in a linear format as well.